# Duplication of columns

Tags: laravel-5

I trying to create foreign keys for my laravel 5.8 project, but I am getting error:
[image]

My migration file

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('chatter_category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('chatter_category_id')->references('id')->on('chatter_categories')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
        Schema::table('chatter_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('chatter_discussion_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('chatter_discussion_id')->references('id')->on('chatter_discussion')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define your relationships within your models and forget about setting foreign keys etc.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

So in your ChatterDiscussion/ChatterPost models (which you may have to create) you would have a function like:

```
public function chatter_category()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ChatterCategory');
}
```

And in your ChatterCategory (whihch you may also need to create) you would have the inverse:

```
public function chatter_discussion()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ChatterDiscussion');
}
public function chatter_post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ChatterPost');
}
```

You can then handle the deletes in each of the delete functions within your models.

Either way, your error is that you are creating the same column name twice. Something like this should work (I have not tested this)

```
Schema::table('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('chatter_category_id')->unsigned()->index()->references('id')->on('chatter_categories')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
        Schema::table('chatter_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('chatter_discussion_id')->unsigned()->index()->references('id')->on('chatter_discussion')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```